# Peculiar HDMI Behaviour on Dell Inspiron 15 5558, No Output on monitor but works fine on TV

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, display, hdmi, dell-inspiron

Bear with me for this weird behaviour that I haven't seen before. 
I have the following laptop: 


**Dell Inspiron 15 5558 Specs:**


Core i7 5500u with Intel HD Graphics

16GB DDR3 RAM

Nvidia Geforce 920M 2GB

Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS dual boot, with all the latest drivers for each that I could find on the website.


I have the following monitor - Dell S2240L (yeah, ironic) having a VGA and a HDMI port.


**What I did:**


1. **Tried to connect the laptop to the monitor, through HDMI in Windows 8.1** - **No output**


2. **Tried to connect the laptop to a Sony Bravia TV, through HDMI in Windows 8.1** - **Instantly detects and outputs my desktop working perfectly.**


3. **Tried to connect the laptop to the monitor, through HDMI in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**, didn't work at first, but ran the following command


`xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 1920x1080 && xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 1920x1080`


**Worked perfectly again**


4. Nothing wrong with the HDMI port of the monitor as PS3 connects to it with the same cable just fine and works perfectly.


Monitor either doesn't detect the laptop at all using one cable and if I used other cable it shows no signal from device and goes to sleep instantly. PS3 works fine with both the cables.


What I could deduce priliminarily is, monitor is passive through HDMI and I have to force HDMI port output (xrandr command in ubuntu) to get it working and I guess since TV has a active HDMI port so it detected Windows 8.1 instantly. Any solutions on how to get it working on the Monitor would be appreciated. 


If I have missed any details, please let me know, this is my first time posting a question on this site.